# What does "\(\)" stand for in this command: grep("-(mean|std)\(\)", x[,2])

Tags: regular-expression, quoting, r

Need to know about the function of `\(\)` in `grep("-(mean|std)\(\)", x[,2])`

Comment: Your question heading and question looks different. You have one extra `\\` in the question heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches `(` and `)` literally.

`()` is used as capturing groups in Extended Regular Expressions (as used by `r`'s `grep()` or the `grep` command with the `-E` option) or Perl Compatible Regular Expression which extend Extended Regular Expressions (as used by `r`'s `grep(..., perl=TRUE)` or some `grep` commands with the `-P` option).

Hence to match `()` literally, `\` is used.

Comment: I didn't understand! May you elaborate!

Comment: So to match a pattern "-mean() or std()" we add "\\(\\)" in grep. right?

Comment: @RishabhVerma i have added explaination. Hope it helps. If you need more do tell.

Comment: @RishabhVerma Yes to match "-match()" or "-std()" you need to add "\(\)"

Comment: @RishabhVerma You can accept the answer if you think it is correct and you are satisfied. This helps other in reading answers.